# Deleting WCFTestClient's Cache - for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, windows, wcf, visual-studio-2010, caching

We're creating WCF services (.NET 3.5) via Visual Studio 2010. When I make a change to the .svc.cs file, save, clean, rebuild and copy to GAC (using WSPBuilder, which recycles the various IIS processes) I still get cached data. Only drastic things like checking in all my files and running a gated checkin build, or restarting the computer clear this 'cache'.

The upshot of this is that the development->testing cycle is extremely slow. But it need not be! Here's my question. Where is the cache that VS2010 or Windows is keeping for WCFTestClient? I can add debug breakpoints and the symbols show up in the debug (so that means on some level I'm using the new assembly) but key things like watches will show old, cached variable values.

Is there a cache somewhere for this data? Looking at the list of .dll files in the output that the WCFTestClient is using when I run debug(F5) shows that it uses the correct .dll (and my observations during debug confirm this.)

I just need to be able to remove (manually if needed) this cache between rebuilds of my assembly. Otherwise, I can't actually rectify problems in the code.

If I'm missing something obvious here, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try deleting your solution .suo file.

Comment: Yep, seems like the cache is in there. If I close the solution, delete the .suo, reopen it and do the compile/copy to GAC/debug the cached data is gone. Thanks a bundle!